# AJAX call killing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div in a parent page that is filled with HTML and Javascript by an AJAX call for HTML.

The loaded Javascript binds a 'change' event to an element in that loaded HTML.

After the first AJAX call, the event always fires. However, on subsequent AJAX calls, it never does.

The parent page itself is filled into a div on a grandparent page. And prior to the child page being filled into the parent page's div, the parent page is filled into the grandparent page's div by a different AJAX call for HTML. Not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

Calling .off() on the object prior to binding the event (using .on) doesn't help at all.

Here is the element:

```
    <select id="groupSelection" name="grouping" style="width:275px;">
        <option value="0" selected>No Grouping - Single Creative Ad Unit</option>
        <option value="1">New Creative Group</option>
        <?php foreach($placementGroups as $placementGroup): ?>
        <option value="<?=$placementGroup->get_id()?>" data-height="<?=$placementGroup->get_height()?>" data-width="<?=$placementGroup->get_width()?>"><?=$placementGroup->get_name()?> - Height: <?=$placementGroup->get_height()?>px x Width: <?=$placementGroup->get_width()?>px</option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```

Here is the binding event:

```
    $('#groupSelection').off().on('change', function() {...});
```

But if I explicitly call $('#groupSelection').change() after the second AJAX call it fires.

What do I need to do? Thanks

Edit:

There is one place in my code where the child calls the ajax function, which not only reloads itself but reloads its parent. When I call $('#groupSelection').off() just before calling the ajax function, it works fine.

However, there are functions in the parent that also reload the child. When I call $('#groupSelection').off() prior to reloading the child in one of these functions, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Why not just use event delegation like `$(document).on('change', '#groupSelection', function() {...});`?

Comment: Same stuff as before unless I didn't do it right.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/4Qs9S/) a fiddle demonstrating event delegation. Before clicking "Replace Children" the two div click handlers will work. Afterwards, only the delegated handler works.

Comment: @cjc343 Your demonstration works, but applying this to my situation doesn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle which demonstrates your situation by simulating the page replacement interactions?

Comment: What I'm doing mimics your fiddler demo. I honestly don't know why it doesn't work for me, there must be something else I'm missing or something in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to work is if I do $('#groupSelection').remove(); prior to making the ajax call from the parent, and I have to do this in every parent function that makes the AJAX call (the ajax call is in a library function that cannot be modified). This seems like an ugly solution to me, would like a prettier one.

I gave this a try because I realized that $("select[id='groupSelection']").length was incrementing each time the ajax call was made. Is there a clean way to garbage collect all events and objects in memory for the HTML being replaced in the div? This has memory leak written all over it.

Edit:

Calling .empty() on the parent div doesn't remove the elements. Only calling .remove() on each of them explicitly does.

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX call replaces the element with the `groupSelection` id, you need to re-create your event handler. An alternative format which doesn't require re-creating your event handler is:

```
$('#someElementWhichIsNotReplacedWhichIsAParentOfgroupSelection').on('change', '#groupSelection', someFunc);
```

Comment: Even when I do something like $(document).on('change', '#groupSelection', function() {...}); from within the topmost parent I still have the same problem.